# Fixed position first list item, with auto width adjustment upon scrollbar

Tags: html, css, list, width, overflow

Is there a way to ensure that the first item of a list always stays at the top of the list (even when the user has scrolled down) and to ensure that this first list item's width adjusts according to whether there is a scrollbar in the list or not (with respect to the other list items).

Currently I can only achieve one or the other, i.e. I can put the first list item outside of the list (above it) and make the list scrollable. The problem is that when there are enough items in the list, the scrollbars come in and shrink the width of the list items, but the "first list item" (that I pulled out of the list) does not shrink it's width as well.

If I put the item inside the list I will avoid this width mismatch problem, but then the first list item will scroll out of view when the user scrolls the list.

The reason why I want the first item to stay put is because the first item is actually a container of headings for the list (side by side).

Is there some way I can get the scrollbar to exist outside of the list or make it overlap the content?

I know I can change the overflow of the list from "auto" to "scroll" and adjust the width of the heading container outside of the list to match the width of the list, but that would be browser and machine dependent (not what I want at all).

Comment: Will be great , if you post some code.

Comment: I don't have a particular code problem, I am after a technique/strategy to solve this problem.

Comment: I found this article: http://css-tricks.com/eliminate-jumps-in-horizontal-centering-by-forcing-a-scroll-bar/ which is quite old though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a `div` with the `position:fixed` attribute around the `li` you want to stay in place.

Comment: "fixed" position completely takes the item out of document flow and the other list items overlap it, so this doesn't work.